# Which module can provide a group address field in drupal 7 ?

Tags: drupal-7

I would like create a field which is a group of drop-down list boxes for user to choose his/her address. The drop-down list boxes are such as: Country, City, Street, and so on.
Which module can provide this function in drupal 7?

Answer (score 0):

This module does exactly what you are looking for: https://drupal.org/project/countries

With it you can create aditional fields also and modify the existing fields. I recommend you to use it with display suite mudule to have more flexibility

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I find the countries module can only set continent and country.It can not set city and street ...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but if people are still looking for an answer you may check out the Address Field Module - https://drupal.org/project/addressfield

It's not going to to offer everything asked but it's worth looking into.